# No puedo hacer push porque me dice que un elemento pesa mucho y no esta

Tags: git, vscode, github, git-push, git-commit

En mi repositorio local por error descargue un exe ahi, lo borre pero ahora lo sigue detectando aunque ya hice commit con el archivo borrado.
[image: Imagen de referencia donde se muestra el archivo descargado y que pessa mas de 100MB y en la imagen2 no esta]

Entonces lo busco en vc pero no me sale, que puedo hacer para solucionarlo.
[image: Imagen2 donde se muestra que el archivo no esta en la carpeta que dice el error]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Sería mejor que coloque el comando y la salida del comando como texto en la pregunta, y no como imagen.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que ese objeto al que hace referencia github en el mensaje de error está *en la historia* de la rama que estás tratando de empujar a github, aunque lo hayas borrado y ya no esté en la punta de la rama. Tendrías que eliminarlo de las revisiones donde está incluído para que entonces github te permita hacer el push. Si la historia de la rama es lineal desde el momento en el que insertaste ese archivo, la forma de corregirlo es sencilla. Buscas la revisión donde ese archivo fue agregado (puedes hacer un `git log --name-status -- js/Apache-XXXXXXXXXX`. Digamos que esa revisión es la X. Entonces haces esto:

```
git rebase -i X~ # incluir el rabo de cochino
# la primera revisión en la lista debería ser X
# cambias la acción de pick a e o edit
# guardas y ejecutas
# git va a arrancar el rebase y se va a detener justo en esa revisión
# borras el archivo, con --cached, si lo quieres mantener en el arbol de trabajo:
gt rm --cached el-archivo
# enmiendas la revisión
git commit --amend --no-edit
# dejas que el rebase corra
git rebase --continue
# el git debe terminar y ya el archivo no está en la historia del proyecyo.
```

Ahora podrías intentar hacer el push

Nota al margen para los que no entiendan por qué se da ese error: esta restricción de los 100 MBs la pone github como política de uso de sus repositorios... y eso aplica para todos los objetos (git objects, quiero decir) que quieran empujar a un repositorio (blobs, trees, revisions, etc... aunque supongo que sería difícil producir revisiones o trees que superen los 100 MBs... pero en fin). No es una restricción de **git**.

Comment: la dll de cefsharp ella solita pesa 150mb XD